# Replace the main image with thumbnails in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Here my script :

```
function changeImage(event){
    event = event || window.event;
    var targetElement = event.target || event.srcElement;

    if (targetElement.tagName == "IMG"){
        document.getElementByClass("img-big-wrap").src = targetElement.getAttribute("src");
        document.getElementById("mainimageLink").href = 'link'+targetElement.getAttribute("data-link")+'.html';
    }
}
```

Inspired of this Answer : [Javascript Gallery - Main Image href change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30035116/javascript-gallery-main-image-href-change)

My HTML :

```
<div class="gallery-wrap">


  <div class="img-big-wrap">
    <a id="mainimagelink" href="<?php echo $data[0][gallery][0][photo];?>">
    <img class="img-big-wrap" src="<?php echo $data[0][gallery][0][photo];?>" alt="">

  </div>
  <div class="img-small-wrap" onclick="changeImage(event)">
    <div class="item-gallery"> <img src="<?php echo $data[0][gallery][1][thumb];?>" data-link="1"> </div>
    <div class="item-gallery"> <img src="<?php echo $data[0][gallery][2][thumb];?>" data-link="2"> </div>
    <div class="item-gallery"> <img src="<?php echo $data[0][gallery][3][thumb];?>" data-link="3"> </div>
    <div class="item-gallery"> <img src="<?php echo $data[0][gallery][4][thumb];?>" data-link="4"> </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

The code is actualy just open me the link of the main image only
I want to change the main image with the thumbnails when I click On, I dont know if what i'm doing is the good solution

Comment: `getElementByClass` there is no such thing. Open dev console to see the error message.

Comment: `getElementByClass` should be `getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Working Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/pjpHBUD4yPihqr7lJKAD?p=preview

```
<div class="gallery-wrap">
    <div>
      <a id="mainimagelink" href="https://blog.conservation.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/ci_19290600_cropped.jpg">
        <img class="img-big-wrap" src="https://blog.conservation.org/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/ci_19290600_cropped.jpg?>" alt="">
      </a>
    <hr/>
    </div>
    <div class="img-small-wrap" ">
    <div class="item-gallery " onclick="changeImage(event) "> <img src="https://s5.favim.com/610/52/Favim.com-winter-nature-small-canon-eos-7d-474348.jpg " data-link="1 "> </div>
    <div class="item-gallery " onclick="changeImage(event) "> <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTfAMUZQLGObfUBSLgnPj5b5C7Ww2DNMtKbwkuTbglK-p1La17BnA " data-link="2 "> </div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

A couple of things you've missed.

1. The HTML DOM was not well constructed. The  tag with id mainimagelink was left unclosed, leading to opening of the main image everytime you clicked on any image.
2. Not sure of your use case but I believe you were trying to create a thumbnail gallery with a preview. Added Image URLs and CSS to simulate the API response.
3. 'img-big-wrap' class was used for the image container and the actual Image itself, which would lead to errors when you try to locate your element with js.
4. document.getElementByClass is not the right name for the method. I believe you were going for 'document.getElementsByClassName' which returns an array as multiple elements can have the same className. 
   Refer to querySelector (most useful of them all):

   https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_queryselector.asp

All the best!

Comment: Refer to using `Code Snippets` as external links can die and others won't be able to access them in the future.

Comment: Thx for the help , i actualy try a new solution but the console return me :  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: That working, i got a problem in my css class, thx for the help !

Comment: @Tensei Happy to help!

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you have used the same class more than once and tried to access it `img-big-wrap`.

There is also no accessor called `getElementByClass` instead use
[`getElementsByClassName`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_getelementsbyclassname.asp) which is an array since you can have multiple divs with the same class.

Typo here `"mainimageLink"` which you called your div with `id="mainimagelink"`, case matters.

I have moved `onclick` into JS using [`addEventListener`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_document_addeventlistener.asp) which saves me passing parameters from the `div`.

Add an `id` into your thumbnail parent div `myImgDiv` and used it to hook an `Event Listener` to it.

Here is what the code looks like (Not many changes were made):

```js
let smallImgDiv = document.getElementById('myImgDiv');

smallImgDiv.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
 let targetElement = e.target || e.srcElement;
  let tagName = targetElement.tagName;
  
  if(tagName === "IMG") {
   document.getElementById('bigImage').src = targetElement.getAttribute("src");
    document.getElementById("mainimagelink").href = 'link' + targetElement.getAttribute("data-link") + '.html';
  }
});
```

```css
.img-small-wrap img{
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
}

.img-big-wrap {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="gallery-wrap">


  <div class="img-big-wrap">
    <a id="mainimagelink" href="#">
    <img id="bigImage" class="img-big-wrap" src="http://via.placeholder.com/300.png" alt="">
    </a>
  </div>

  <div id="myImgDiv" class="img-small-wrap">
    <div class="item-gallery"> <img src="https://getuikit.com/v2/docs/images/placeholder_200x100.svg" data-link="1"> </div>
    <div class="item-gallery"> <img src="https://cdn.dribbble.com/users/312581/screenshots/1676038/female-placeholder_1x.png" data-link="2"> </div>
    <div class="item-gallery"> <img src="https://d30y9cdsu7xlg0.cloudfront.net/png/1134418-200.png" data-link="3"> </div>
    <div class="item-gallery"> <img src="https://source.sierrawireless.com/~/media/developer%20zone/icons/sw_dz_icons_placeholder.ashx?h=240&la=en&w=240" data-link="4"> </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I try your code , the console return me this error : 'vue_vehicle.php:91 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
    at vue_vehicle.php:91'

Comment: That working, i got a problem in my css class, thx for the help !